# How to wrap jQuery UI Dialog in a div container?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My web portlet is being deployed to the liferay environment, which means that there are multiple jQuery css themes.  The way I have been solving the multiple theme issue is by wrapping my portlet with my own class and adding that class as a container to the jquery-ui css (for example, using `.my-portlet .ui-dialog {}`).

When I create a dialog using jQuery UI though, the dialog container is given the class `.ui-dialog`, so the theme becomes that of whatever theme liferay is using.  My solution would be to wrap the dialog in my own div with a class of `my-portlet', which should cause it to use my own ui theme.

How do I do this though?  Using `$(#item).dialog()` automatically applies the `ui-dialog` class as the head container.  I don't really want to have to modify the jQuery code.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have different dialogs, which need to be moved to different wrappers, then you can simply use

```
$('.ui-dialog').appendTo('#wrapper');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **appendTo** but you must have jquery-ui 1.10.0 or highter

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ appendTo: "#someElem" });
```

Check jquery-ui documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to jQueryUI 1.10, all dialogs were automagically wrapped in a `<div>` container and then moved into the DOM *body* element.

If you wanted it to sit elsewhere in the DOM you had to re-parent it within another element.  To further complicate matters you then have to reset its `draggable` properties too:

```
var dlg = $('#item').data('dialog').uiDialog;
$(dlg).appendTo('#newparent');
$(dlg).draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
```

I suspect that this approach won't help you though if your intent is to wrap an extra container div around the jQuery UI supplied container.

Alternatively, you *might* be able to get away with using the [`dialogClass`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-dialogClass) option when you create the dialog to add an extra class to the dialog container.

Comment: will using the `dialogClass` get rid of the `.ui-dialog` classes applied to the dialog container?  Or will it just add a class?

Comment: @JohnLeehey the manual suggests they'll be added, rather than replacing.  I haven't tried it, though!  If you want to remove the `.ui-dialog` class that's easily achieved, although it may have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like this?

```
$('#item').dialog().wrapAll('<div class="my-portlet"></div>');
```

Comment: that'll create a new div _between_ the jQuery UI dialog container and the original content.