# Jquery dialog not loaded within specified div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I observe that a Jquery dialog loaded using `load()` is not loaded within the matched element.  Here's my parent document:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#button1').click(function() {
      $('#loaded-dialog-wrapper').load('child.html');
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='button1'>Click</button>

  <div id='loaded-dialog-wrapper'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the document containing the dialog that is loaded:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var dialogOpts = {
  width: 600,
  height: 400,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: false,
  buttons: [{text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close");} }],
};

$('#loaded-dialog').dialog(dialogOpts);
$('#loaded-dialog').dialog('open');

});
</script>

<div id='loaded-dialog'>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

`#loaded-dialog-wrapper` is loaded, but it does not contain `#loaded-dialog`; it only has the `script` node.  Instead, `#loaded-dialog` is contained inside a `div` that is added as a child to the `body` node.  If I close the dialog, the dialog goes away, and when I click the button again, the dialog is displayed and a new `div` is created in the same manner as before.  If I change the contents inside `#loaded-dialog`, on the second opening, the dialog that is displayed does not contain the updated content.  However, the `#loaded-dialog` containing the new content is contained in the second created `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JqueryUI moves the dialog div inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213445/2233706), and adds it as a child of the `body` node.  This is what I observed.  To get around this, I destroyed added div upon closing the dialog.  This was done in `dialogOpts` in child.html:

```
var dialogOpts = {
  width: 600,
  height: 400,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  draggable: false,
  buttons: [{text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close");} }],
  close: function() {
    $('#loaded-dialog').dialog('destroy'); // To remove the Jquery stuff
    $('#loaded-dialog').remove(); // To remove the div
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your dialog options into your main document.
Then assign the click directly to loaded-dialog-wrapper:

```
$('#button1').on('click',function() {
  $('#loaded-dialog-wrapper').dialog(dialogOpts).html('Place your message here');
});
```

You don't need that 2nd document child.html

Comment: I would like to keep all the code in child.html.  I don't want parent.html to know whatever child.html contains.  It should load whatever is inside child.html.  Is this possible?

Comment: note, that load() is deprecated since 1.8 http://api.jquery.com/load-event/
I would expect, that you have to place at least your logic into the main document, so that this will be rendered by the document.ready()

Comment: What you are referring to is the event handler, but the version of `load` that loads from a server is [not deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  When you refer to logic, are you referring to all the JS code in child.html?

Comment: To answer your question, if I call child.html from the browser, just "Text" is displayed.  The dialog is not.  This is because the Jquery library is not included.

Comment: As I told before: I suppose, the javascript is not rendered by load.
Documentation tells, load gets html data from server, so no javascript is executed.

Comment: Load must be executing the JS code that is loaded with the rest of the server data.  The dialog is opened using `$('#loaded-dialog').dialog('open')` in child.html.  If I comment that line out, the dialog is not opened.

Comment: finally, I setup your files on my system and find it working well in IE, FF and Chrome. Developer tool shows, that the click is inserting the whole content into the '#loaded-dialog-wrapper'-div as you would excpect it

Comment: That's not what I observe.  I observe `#loaded-dialog` within a div that is a sibling to `#loaded-dialog-wrapper`, which only has the script node.  What do you see if you change the contents of `#loaded-dialog` and close and reopen the dialog without refreshing the page?